# Error al usar osmosdr en GNURadio

Tags: linux

Tras realizar la instalación de gnuradio en Kali Linux via `apt-get install gnuradio`, abrir gnuradio-companion y crear un simple grafo que hace uso del componente `osmosdr_source` me salta el siguiente error cuando inicio su ejecución:

> Executing: /usr/bin/python3 -u
>   /root/Documentos/Common-Tools/hackrf_one/scripts/untitled.py
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/root/Documentos/Common-Tools/hackrf_one/scripts/untitled.py", line
>   161, in 
>       main()   File "/root/Documentos/Common-Tools/hackrf_one/scripts/untitled.py", line
>   139, in main
>       tb = top_block_cls()   File "/root/Documentos/Common-Tools/hackrf_one/scripts/untitled.py", line
>   96, in **init**
>       self.osmosdr_source_0 = osmosdr.source( AttributeError: module 'osmosdr' has no attribute 'source'

Alguien tiene idea de porque podría ser? Quizaá incompatibilidades con la versión de python?

Muchas gracias.

Un saludo.